# Angular2 routing: canDeactivate limitations

Tags: angular2-routing

I've got a form in angular2. If it's dirty (with unsaved changes), I want to restrict the user from navigating away.

Research shows that the `canDeactivate` route guard is the way to do it.

Google led me to [this github file](https://github.com/mosh-hamedani/angular2-course/blob/master/app/prevent-unsaved-changes-guard.service.ts) which seems to implement what I want.

```
import { CanDeactivate } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

export interface FormComponent {
    form: FormGroup;
}

export class PreventUnsavedChangesGuard implements CanDeactivate < FormComponent > {
    canDeactivate(component: FormComponent) {
        if (component.form.dirty)
            return confirm('You have unsaved changes. Are you sure you want to navigate away?');

        return true;
    }
}
```

Now, I've put this service in my project, injected it in my form component, added it to my routing module as so...

```
const routes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
    loadChildren: 'app/main/main.module#MainModule',
    canActivate: [AuthenticationGuard],
}, {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    canDeactivate: [PreventUnsavedChangesGuard]
}, ]
```

and included it in the app module's providers array.

Now, it seems to work. In case I have unsaved changes when I click the browser's back button. I get the confirmation dialog. However, **when I input a new URL in the address bar, I don't get the confirmation**. Also, I'm able to close the tab when I have unsaved changes.

Are these known limitations of `canDeactivate`, or am I doing something wrong. How do I get the behavior I want? (Confirmation dialog if the user attempts to close tab or navigate away using the address bar?)

Comment: I see the same.Any solution for this issue?

Comment: @Sophia Not with angular. I had to listen to the native `onbeforeuload` event of the window.

Comment: thanks @Snowman, I try to add `canDeactivate: [PreventUnsavedChangesGuard]`, but It just work with parent routes and not work with child routes :(

Comment: @Sophia: Yes, I was getting some weird behavior too. Seems like there's still a few bugs in the current version. Hope they fix it soon. Good luck.